# 'Passing list-likes to .loc in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a following list of dates:

```
date_list 
DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-10', '2015-07-13', '2015-07-14', '2015-07-15',
               '2015-07-16', '2015-07-17', '2015-08-20', '2015-09-21',
               '2015-09-22', '2015-09-23']
```

To access the value for rows in pandas for these dates i did this:

```
df['Close'].loc[dates_list]
```

This produces the following error:

```
KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported
```

How can i get the row values for these `DateTtimeindex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works like a charm:

```py
df.loc[date_list, 'Close']
```

Test example, loosely based on what you provided - feel free to clarify the details, if something is off comparing to your use case:

```py
import pandas as pd

date_list=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-10', '2015-07-13', '2015-07-14', '2015-07-15',
               '2015-07-16', '2015-07-17', '2015-08-20', '2015-09-21',
               '2015-09-22', '2015-09-23'])

df=pd.DataFrame({'Close': list("abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz"), 'dt': ['2015-07-10', '2015-07-13', '2015-07-14', '2015-07-15','2017-01-01','2017-01-03','2015-07-01','2005-09-07', '2018-02-04',
               '2015-07-16', '2015-07-17', '2015-08-20', '2015-09-21','2019-04-06','2002-04-07','2002-05-19',
               '2015-09-22', '2015-09-23','2020-07-07', '2020-06-08', '2018-02-01', '2000-04-04', '2001-09-09', '2008-08-03', '2008-09-01']})
df['dt']=pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])
df=df.set_index('dt')
res=df.loc[date_list, 'Close']

>>> res

2015-07-10    a
2015-07-13    b
2015-07-14    c
2015-07-15    d
2015-07-16    j
2015-07-17    k
2015-08-20    l
2015-09-21    m
2015-09-22    r
2015-09-23    s
Name: Close, dtype: object
```